# Angular : Can't assign directive to dynamically created content using *ngComponentOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-directive, dynamically-generated

https://plnkr.co/edit/KrAV2oJWjSDMiqIyqtBi?p=preview

Got a component that creates , compiles and inject a component.
I got two components that I am creating foo-bar and foopica-bar.
I've created an Directive ContentEditableDirective but somehow does not see the directive.

On load it should call the directive and add background color yellow to the native Element style.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myHighlight]',

})

export class ContentEditableDirective {

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
       console.log(' el.nativeElement.style',  el.nativeElement.style)
    }
     ngAfterContentInit(){
     console.log('calling me again')}
}
```

Comment: Move `ContentEditableDirective` directive from AppModule `declarations` to SharedModule `declarations`. https://plnkr.co/edit/xGpnSn95TaMo7R4BVyIu?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui, is there a way to create so that I could be passing data to parent from injected child?